# Передача класса в функцию в c++

Tags: c++, классы, функции

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Example {
  public:
    int grid[30][30];
    Example();
    void someChange();
};

void someFunction (Example);

int main() {
    Example m;
    m.someChange();
    cout << m.grid[3][3] << endl;
    someFunction(m);
    cout << m.grid[3][3];
    return 0;
}

Example::Example() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; ++j)
            grid[i][j] = 1;
}

void Example::someChange() {
    ++grid[3][3];
}

void someFunction(Example m) {
    m.someChange();
}
```

Как нужно передать класс в функцию someFunction(Example), чтоб при её вызове элемент m.grid[3][3] изменился?

Comment: По ссылке - как `void someFunction(Example& m)`

Answer (score 3):

Передать его по ссылке:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Example {
  public:
    int grid[30][30];
    Example();
    void someChange();
};
void someFunction(Example &m) {
    m.someChange();
}

int main() {
    Example m;
    m.someChange();
    cout << m.grid[3][3] << endl;
    someFunction(m);
    cout << m.grid[3][3];
    return 0;
}

Example::Example() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; ++j)
            grid[i][j] = 1;
}

void Example::someChange() {
    ++grid[3][3];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, только при объявлении после main() тоже исправить надо)

Comment: ок, исправил ошибку.